# Как настроить инет на debian'е?

Tags: debian, linux

Linux никогда не юзал.

Comment: Слишком мало исходных данных.
- с графикой линукс или без
- проводная или безпроводная сеть

да и лучше задавать такой вопрос на Руткоде:)

Comment: И подскажите как на цбунте 10.04 настроить проводной интернет

Comment: @Vynder Это правильно спрашивать на [РутКоде](http://admin.hashcode.ru).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "iface eth0 inet dhcp" >> /etc/network/interfaces
ifup eth0
```

а ещё помотрите [тут](http://support.dobroe.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&Itemid=15).